# Cannot import name App when using Celery in Flask

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am writing a simple Flask app that uses Celery to run a background task, but when i try to run the app on terminal i get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 2, in <module>
    from flask_celery import make_celery
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_celery.py", line 16, in <module>
    from celery.app import App, AppPickler, current_app as current_celery
ImportError: cannot import name App
```

Here is the code that i am using:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_celery import make_celery

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["CELERY_BROKER_URL"] = "amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672//"

celery = make_celery(app)


@celery.task(name='server.reverse')
def reverse(string):
    return string[::-1]


@app.route("/process/<name>")
def process(name):
    reverse.delay(name)
    return "I sent an async request!"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You receive the error because `App` is not published by the `celery.app` module, see [the code](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/49f6b572e571bcb5b668ce3d25507668c877102f/celery/app/__init__.py#L13). Also, it seems that you are using `flask_celery`, which is [not the recommended way](https://github.com/ask/flask-celery#using-flask-with-celery) how to use Flask with Celery now:

> From Celery 3.0 the Flask-Celery integration package is no longer recommended and you should use the standard Celery API instead.

Here's the part of the Flask documentation that covers integration with Celery:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/celery/